# Chef not_if/only_if command result and string comparison

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to run a command and compared its output but it appears my bellow code isn't working as I would expect it to.

```rb
execute 'testcond' do
  command "echo success"
  only_if {"lsb_release -rs" == '22.04'}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guard you are using relies on the return status of the expression within `{ }`. The expression you have is more like comparing two strings `lsb_release -rs` and `22.04`. This evaluates to false, and as expected the execution is skipped.

I'd recommend using node attribute that Chef collects about the node. Example:

```rb
execute 'testcond' do
  command 'echo success'
  only_if { node['platform_version'] == '22.04' }
end
```

If you would like to use the command, we can get the result of the command in a variable, and then compare it within `only_if` guard.

```rb
distro_ver = `lsb_release -rs`

execute 'testcond' do
  command 'echo success'
  only_if { distro_ver.chomp! == '22.04' }
end
```

Note that I'd to use `chomp` as output of the command adds a newline (`\n`).

Comment: Your first example is invalid since it just checks whether the literal string `"lsb_release -rs == '22.04'"` is truethy (which it always is). It does not execute the command as you are passing a block there. Your second example is correct and generally preferred however.

Comment: That's a good point. My answer now has both working examples.

Comment: Was going to comment out on this as well @HolgerJust. The 2nd one with the node is working on the other hand.